# Dynamically add/change attribute on component selector

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ion-col',
    templateUrl: 'components-field.html'
})

export class FieldComponent {
    @HostBinding('attr.layout')
    layout = '¯\_(ツ)_/¯';
    element: any;
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello ComponentsFieldComponent Component');
    }

    setElement(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }


}
```

In this example I can dynamically set the value of "layout" attribute. this example will do :

```
<ion-col layout="¯\_(ツ)_/¯"></ion-col>
```

**BUT** I want to set the name of the attribute dynamically in order to achieve this :

```
<ion-col col-3></ion-col>
<ion-col col-5></ion-col>
<ion-col col-12></ion-col>
```

I could create 12 versions of my component.I won't. Any idea ?

Comment: hmmm...are `col-3` etc. attributes or *directives*?

Comment: @joh04667 col-x is an attribute of the ionic grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way to dynamically add or remove attributes via template binding in Angular, since attributes themselves are usually supposed to be static and have their *values* changed instead.

It's not impossible, though. I would recommend folding the logic into a directive:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[colThing]'
})
export class ColThingDirective {

  @Input('colThing') 
  set colCriteria(value) {
   this.doLogicToChangeAttributes(value);
  }

  public attributeList = ['col-5', 'col-3'];

  constructor(private _r: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

  doLogicToChangeAttributes(value) {
    if (value === 'col-5-criteria') {
      this.removeAttributes();
      this._r.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'col-5', '');
    }

  }

  removeAttributes() {
    this.attributeList.forEach(s => this._r.removeAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, s));
  }
}
```

In component:

```
export class FieldComponent {

  @HostBinding('[ColThingDirective]') someCriteriaToChangeAttribute; // <--
 @Input to directive

}
```

Based on this use case, however, I'd be very surprised if there wasn't better built-in functionality behavior. I would have assumed that these attributes are either actually *directives* (which would need to be changed via a `HostBinding`) or that there's some built-in way to handle what I assume is responsiveness. It's pretty unusual to have attributes there just for styling purposes.

Comment: I don't understand why they handled the responsiveness with full attributes instead of just using class or at least col="3" this is a real PITA (pain in ...).

Comment: If that's not too much to ask can you provide an example about the usage of this directive in my component example.

Comment: sure, but since I don't know which criteria you're using to change the attributes on, it'll have to stay vague.

Comment: sure, this.element contains a property (Number)this.element.col_size.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I could come up with so far...

```
<ion-col [attr.col-12]="myValue === 'col-12' ? '' : null"
         [attr.col-6]="myValue === 'col-6' ? '' : null">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to add attribute in component selector (angular 12).

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: './user.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class User {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let value = 'demo'; // value can be static or dynamic
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('key', value);
    }
}
```

Output -

```
<user key="demo">...</user>
```